# CSS - can't get style properties

Tags: css, properties

I have a div called "box" but i can't use css style from file style.css

```
<div id="right">


        <?php
            $cc = 1;
        for($i=1; $i<=71; $i++)
            {
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE product_id='".$i."'");
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
                $t="img/";
                $file = $t .$row[1];
                if($cc % 5 == 1) echo "<ul>";
                echo '<li><div id="box"><a href="#"><img src =thumb.php?file=' . $file . '&size=120></a></div></li>';
                if($cc % 5 ==0) echo "</ul>";
                $cc ++;
                } ?>


    </div>
```

If i put the css style declaration inline it's working

```
 #right {
/*margin-left: 12em;*/
padding-left: 50px;
border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
 #right img {
border: 1px solid #CCC;
 }
#right li { display: inline-block; }


#box {width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: white; text-align: center;padding-top:20px;}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: CSS runs/works ***client-side***, could you please post the rendered html, as seen in the browser ('view source')?

Comment: Can you post the relevent lines in style.css?

Comment: I solved the problem, i refreshed the css page :)

Answer (score 1):

Post your style.css (to make sure it is correct), and full page html source (to make sure you include style.css correctly).

CSS should look like:

```
#box {
width: 150px; 
height: 150px; 
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
padding-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: #box {width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: white; text-align: center;padding-top:20px;}

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite of the first statement:

```
echo '<li><div id="box"><a href="#"><img src="thumb.php?file=' . $file . '&size=120"></a></div></li>';
```

Minor rewrite of the second statement:

```
echo '<li><div style="width: 150px; height: 150px; background-color: white; text-align: center; padding-top:20px;">';
```

Try them out and let me know if it works a bit better (some parts of your HTML was a bit malformed, so I adjusted them).

Also, it wouldn't hurt if you enclosed the relevant `<link rel="stylesheet" href="link_to_stylesheet.css" />`and also the actual css for `div#box`.